# Make Windows explorer execute multiple copy command in sequence

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Let's say you start with copying some files (`file_glob_A`) from disk C to disk D. And while the copying is happening, you want to copy some more files (`file_glob_B`) from C to D. So you just do the copy & paste on `file_glob_B` when `file_glob_A` is being copied. What's gonna happen here is that the two copy actions would happen simultaneously. And what I want to achieve here is to make Windows execute the copy commands in sequence, so that the `file_glob_B` would only be copied if the copying of `file_glob_A` is finished.

Is it possible in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: It's possible but complicated by writing an AutoHotKey script. It's not a simple matter.